# Java Insertion Sorting

Tags: java, sorting, insertion

Here is a method to perform insertion sorting in Java that I encountered while learning AP Computer Science:

```
public static void insertionSort(int[] x)
{
    for (int i=1;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        int temp = x[i];
        int j=i-1;
        while (temp<x[j]&&j>=0)
        {
            x[j+1]=x[j];
            j--;
        }
        x[j+1]=temp;
    }
}
```

Logically, I think the code is correct. However, when I try to sort a list using the method by using the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] numList ={9,3,12,765,23};
    insertionSort(numList);
    for (int num:numList)
    {
     System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

I get the following exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 5

What is the problem here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: modify your condition for  while as below, that should solve the problem :     while (j>=0 && temp<x[j])

Comment: Look at the entire stacktrace You'll see something like in it `Test.insertionSort(Test.java:42)` it tells that line 42 is causing the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've hit an evaluation order issue. Your condition (`temp < x[j]` and `j >= 0`) is correct, but due to the order you've written them, `x[j]` is evaluated to compare with `temp` before it's compared with 0. Reverse your conditions to `j >=  0 && temp < x[j]` to resolve.

Thanks to short circuit evaluation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), `x[j]` will not be evaluated due to `j >= 0` being false.

Answer (score 0):

use `while (j>=0&&temp<x[j])`
not
`while (temp<x[j]&&j>=0)`

Answer (score 0):

In while loop in insertionSort method your statement should be like this

```
while (j >= 0 && x[j] > temp)
```